# Vectorizing or otherwise speeding up/eliminating for loops in R for Practical Applicaiton

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization, vectorization

My background as a c programmer has put for loops into the way I think, so I usually start with them, and try to optimize once everything "works the way I want it to.  I have a large case, but we'll break it down piece by piece (unless the community thinks that its better to lay it all bare in one question.  I think if people are searching, it's easier to find the parts).

Here goes.  After cleaning and paring down some data, I have something similar to a much larger version of:

```
library(data.table)
bsdata<-as.data.table(structure(list(Date = c("1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/1/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017", "1/2/2017"), Loc = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), Product = c("D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E","E", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F", "F"), Version = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 11L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Count = c(3L, 1L, 144L, 234L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1776L, 654L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2863L, 3L, 1L, 144L, 234L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1776L, 654L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2863L, 3L, 1L, 144L, 234L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1776L, 654L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2863L, 3L, 1L, 144L, 234L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1776L, 420L, 234L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2867L), Call = c(9L, 1L, 10L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 4L, 10L, 7L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 10L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 1L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 0L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 7L, 4L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L), Email = c(3L, 9L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 10L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 5L, 7L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 4L), Ticket = c(4L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 9L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 6L), `Ticket Close` = c(8L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 10L, 7L, 7L, 10L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 5L, 0L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("Date", "Loc", "Product", "Version", "Count", "Call", "Email", "Ticket", "Ticket_Close"), row.names = c(NA, -62L), class = "data.frame"))
bsdata[,Date := as.Date(Date,format = "%m/%d/%Y")]
bsdata[,Loc := as.factor(Loc)]
bsdata[,Product := as.factor(Product)]
bsdata[,Version := as.factor(Version)]
```

From here I aggregate them by day, location, product and version, then start 2 nested for loops that go through every location (in the real data there are 21, and every Product.  My code looks for a change in count over a certain threshold, and returns that row for statistics later.  Currently I have

```
Threshold <- 10
MinTH <- Threshold * 10
#Setup allocation:
OVer   <- character()
OLoc   <- character()
ODate  <- as.Date(character(),origin="1970-01-01")
OProd  <- character()
OCount <- integer()
# Pare down for quicker use:
DateRange <- sort(unique(bsdata$Date)) # Find what dates are in this data
data <- bsdata[,.("Count"=sum(Count),"Calls"=sum(Call),"Emails"=sum(Email), "Tickets"=sum(Ticket),"Closed"=sum(Ticket_Close)),by=.(Date,Loc,Version,Product)]
agg <- data[,.SD[which.max(Count)],by=.(Loc,Product)]    # Max of all days
agg <- agg[Count > MinTH,.(Loc,Product,Count)]
# Begin Loops
for(lel in levels(data$Loc)){          # For all sites
  LocData <- data[Loc == lel,.(Date,Version,Product,Count)]    # Cut data: Only data from this site and only what's needed
  for(Prod in agg[Loc == lel,Product]){ 
    MaxDeviceCount <- agg[(Loc == lel) & (Product == Prod),Count]  # grab max
    PLocData <- LocData[Product == Prod] # Cut data to only Product
    V_in_Block <- as.character(unique(PLocData[,Version])) # Retrieve all Versions in this block
    for(V in V_in_Block){  # For each Version get delta by day, first day is full delta.
      VPLD <- PLocData[Version == V]
      VPLD <- VPLD[order(Date)]
      nr <- nrow(VPLD)
      if(nr > 1)VPLD[,Delta := Count - shift(Count,1)]
      VPLD$Delta[1] <- VPLD$Count[1]
      VPLD[,trigg := (abs(Delta) > Threshold)]
      if(any(VPLD$trigg)){    # Trigger if day before was more or less over a certain number
        enn <- sum(VPLD$trigg)
        OLoc   <- c(OLoc  , rep(lel,enn))
        ODate  <- c(ODate , VPLD$Date[VPLD$trigg])
        OVer   <- c(OVer  , rep(V,enn))
        OProd  <- c(OProd , rep(Prod,enn))
        OCount <- c(OCount, VPLD$Delta[VPLD$trigg])
      } # append to output vectors
    }
  }
}
# Create "trigger" data table
OUT <- data.table(Loc=OLoc,Date=ODate,Ver=OVer,Prod=OProd,Change=OCount)
```

There were more for loops before (in the initial conceptual phase, as I learn more about R), but after some digging, I've gotten this far.  The data is ~3 million rows (to develop on, likely much more when deployed) and this already moves pretty fast.  But in trying to "think more R-like" I'm wondering if there's a way to turn those for loops into -apply like statements or some other vectorized way of doing things.  Much of what I've found is very academic, working with data-sets that are beautiful and fall into nice categories where "pre-allocating things" is relatively easy.  Since I don't know the Products/Dates/Versions beforehand, I usually try to program in a way that can handle those things.  We do know it once we have the dataset, so , if there's a way to do stuff "pre-loop" that sets things up, that'd be nice, but it would have to work for a varied number of Products/Dates/Versions.  (and the stuff that comes next is a little more complicated).  Once I move on, I'll link that question back to here to continue the "story" for anyone seeking practical, but complex, examples.

Thanks

Comment: Are you growing any vectors inside the for loops? That's a big 'no-no' in terms of speed, in R. Each time you grow a list, it makes a call to memory, which is very time consuming. For instance, at the end of the loop, you're growing `OLoc`, `ODate`, etc. Try to pre-allocate the length of those vectors before the loop begins.

Comment: For instance, like, `OCount <- vector("integer", length = 10)`.

Comment: I don't know how long those vectors are going to be.  the loop is to discover where the triggers are, so it can actually build up those vectors.  Technically, I could pre-allocate them to be "worst case" there's a change every day on every product on every firmware, but that seems wasteful, memory-wise.

Comment: Hmmm... That's too bad. There'd be a *substantial* improvement in speed if you could figure that out before starting the loop.

Comment: This would be a more appropriate question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . Having said that, there's a ton of content on this topic you can already learn from on SO.

Comment: I'm certain there is, because this is where I am after having worked on this for 2 weeks and scouring SO for the right way to do this.  As I said in the post, many things on here are very academic (i.e. the datasets are beautiful and work the first time) and don't fit nicely into practical purposes.   Thanks for the tip about codereview, though, I didn't even know that existed

Comment: The impression I formed on reading your question is that you wanted us to do a full review of code that does multiple things, but not efficiently. You didn't show any error messages or indicate what the correct result would be. I decided it was not a suitable SO question. (I suppose you could honestly say I was too lazy for your question.) But perhaps if you narrowed the question down to a single transformation it might become suitable.

Comment: I'd like to end up with a full review, but I am breaking it into one piece at time (this is only part of my code, and I made it de-identified per company policy). The ask for this part is "Can I eliminate the for loops, or is this the best I can hope for, not knowing how many TRUE's I will find in my trigger search", so there is a specific question here.